# Set space quota of HDFS in java

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, hdfs

I am tryging to set space quota for HDFS using Hadoop Java API, however, I can only find getSpaceQuota method in ContentSummary class. Basically I want the code to achieve the same function as `sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 1k /quotasdir` command. Is there any API having set space quota method? Or any better idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Apache Hadoop codebase, the code for the `hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota` command is in the [`DFSAdmin`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.2-RC2/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/tools/DFSAdmin.java#L201-L204) class.  If you read through that code, you'll see that it ultimately delegates to the [`DistributedFileSystem#setQuota`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.2-RC2/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DistributedFileSystem.java#L738) method.  That method implements an RPC to the NameNode to modify the quota.

If you want to reimplement this functionality in your own Java program, then you'll likely need to get an instance of `FileSystem`, downcast it to `DistributedFileSystem`, and then call `DistributedFileSystem#setQuota`.

Please be aware that Apache Hadoop does not provide a strong backward compatibility guarantee for the `DistributedFileSystem` class.  That means that it would be possible for your code to break after an upgrade to a new Hadoop version.  The class is annotated as `LimitedPrivate` and `Unstable`.  The [Apache Hadoop Compatibility](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Compatibility.html) documentation describes the meaning of these annotations in detail.  There is currently no guaranteed public, stable API for changing quota from a custom program.

Comment: Thanks for your explicit answer! It does work! A little question regarding `DistributedFileSystem#setQuota`, if I only want to set space quota, is it OK to call `dfs.setQuota(path, Long.MAX_VALUE, some_number)`? And if I want to implement a method to clear the space quota, just call `dfs.setQuota(path,  Long.MAX_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE)`? Thanks again.

Comment: Your understanding is correct about only setting one of the quotas; you can pass `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  However, to clear the quota, you would need to pass `-1L`.  The [`HdfsConstants`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.2-RC2/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/HdfsConstants.java#L56-L58) class defines these special constants that mean "don't change this quota" and "reset the quota".